# How to force logout of Kubuntu local desktop user

Tags: kubuntu, logout

As the admin user on Kubuntu 12.04.2 LTS how can I force a 2nd or 3rd local desktop user tty session to shutdown without having to switch user and logging in or without killing individual processes?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/358835/force-logout-a-user

Comment: I was hoping that someone had a KDE specific GUI based solution to log out a user gracefully.

Comment: "Gracefully" and "force" don't go well together...

Comment: @jeremy true :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have the following simple commandline solution as a response to my question:

> When my son (Adam) leaves himself logged in, I type this:

```
sudo skill -TERM -u adam
```

When looking at "man skill" it says:

> These tools are probably obsolete and unportable. The command syntax is poorly defined. Consider using the killall, pkill, and pgrep commands instead.

Perhaps the better solution:

```
sudo killall -TERM -u adam
```

These commands are not exactly what I had in mind but it is quick and easy to do and works perfectly to close a session left logged in by another user. A simple GUI solution would be nice.

Comment: SIGTERM is the default signal, so the `-TERM` option can be omitted and you can just use `sudo killall -u adam`.